# How to include \r in this mqtt message when running command-line mqtt client?

Tags: mqtt, command-line-tool

I am using a command-line mqtt client. https://github.com/shirou/mqttcli

I would like to publish a message with \r carriage return character inside. Below is what I did.

```
mqtt-cli mqtt.test.com topic "mqtt_msg 1\r"
```

However, the carriage return character is not sent. Instead, the ASCII "\r" characters are sent. How can I put the \r carriage return inside the mqtt message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
mqtt-cli mqtt.test.com topic "mqtt_msg 1\\r"
```

You need to add the extra `\` as escape character.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the '^' is the escape char for windows

So something like:

```
mqtt-cli mqtt.test.com topic "mqtt_msg 1^
"
```

Where you add the '^' char and then press return

That may send both a \r and \n

Comment: hardillb, I have tested your answer but it does not work. ^ is sent together inside the MQTT message. :(